# Twitter Bootstrap3: get current carousel index number via clicking and automatic

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

In bootstrap3 last version for 4 items in carousel:

```
   <!-- Carousel nav -->
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

in `right carouse control` I get current number index and do something with it.

```
$(".right").click(function(){
    idx = $('.carousel-inner div.active').index()+1;
    if(idx == 4)  idx = 0;
    animateBorder(idx);
});
```

also for left:

```
$(".left").click(function(){
    idx = $('.carousel-inner div.active').index()-1;
    if(idx == -1)  idx = 3;
    animateBorder(idx);
});
```

it works well.

So I want use `animateBorder()` function for auto change slide.

I use this:

```
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
    idx = $('.carousel-inner div.active').index() + 1;
    if(idx == 4)  idx = 0;
    animateBorder(idx);

});
```

it works well.

but when I click on left button, both animateBorder() in second and third codes run.

how can I control it?

Comment: Please create a working example (snippet) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must delete the animateborder functions in right and left click events.
Check it out in console in fiddle. There's no console.log("animateborderf") in right or left click events but, it is firing when you click them.
https://jsfiddle.net/h73yp2o3/

```
$(".right").click(function(){
    idx = $('.carousel-inner div.active').index()+1;
    if(idx == 4)  idx = 0;
});
$(".left").click(function(){
    idx = $('.carousel-inner div.active').index()+1;
    if(idx == 4)  idx = 0;
});
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
    idx = $('.carousel-inner div.active').index() + 1;
    if(idx == 4)  idx = 0;
    console.log("animateborderf");

});
```

The situation is when user clicks right or left button, carousel slides and when carousel slides slide.bs.carousel event is firing. so the animateborder function calls twice in your code.

Edit: 
https://jsfiddle.net/h73yp2o3/2/ This is better I guess.